# PHP: what is wrong in parsing this JSON

Tags: php, json, parsing

Can you please tell me what is wrong with parsing any JSON ouput.

I am using this code
   $stats = json_decode($json, true);

```
    if ($stats == null && json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
 throw new \LogicException(sprintf("Failed to parse json string '%s', error: '%s'", $json , json_last_error_msg()));
```

}

Thanks

Comment: If you validate your JSON in first link from http://jsonlint.com/ you can see error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) it's highlighting that the entries that come back as NaN are not valid.  This is because they are unquoted values.  You either need to accommodate for this in your creation script for the JSON, or alter your datasource to not return NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

In your first json you will see error

```
"OrganicSocialShare":NaN,
"PaidSocialShare":NaN,
```

Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.